# PHP script JQuery grabs wrong number of elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, show-hide

I've been using JQuery to show/hide elements based on login-status, however I've run into some unexpected results, here's the code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#uploadform").hide();
    });
</script>
```

This hides the form if the user is not logged in.

```
    <h2 id="needlogon"> You need to be logged in </h2>
    <a id="needlogon" href="index.php"> Back to start </a>
```

These are to be shown only if the user is not logged in

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['cid'])){
   echo '<script>
           $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#uploadform").show();
           $("needlogon").hide();
           });
         </script>';
}
?>
```

The uploadform is shown/hid as intented, but the needlogon elements are not hidden when the condition ($_SESSION['cid']) is set. The only way it works is if i change the ID's of the elements to needlogon1 and needlogon2, and changing the JQuery to:

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['cid'])){
   echo '<script>
           $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#uploadform").show();
           $("#needlogon1").hide();
           $("#needlogon2").hide();
           });
         </script>';
}
?>
```

I'm sure I'm just missing something silly, anyone know what it is?

Comment: You do know that this doesn't, in any way keep people from using your upload form without logging in, right?

Comment: ids are singular. You can only have one element with the same id

Comment: and you miss the # here : $("needlogon").hide();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, your jQuery selector is off:

```
// $("needlogon").hide();
$("#needlogon").hide(); // you forgot the #
```

Having said that, you're using an ID -- which is supposed to be *unique*. You might want to change the two usages of `needlogin` to a `class` instead of `id`, and then your selector would be `.needlogon` like so:

```
$(".needlogon").hide();
```

Comment: Oh, I knew it was something stupid, thanks a lot, I'll start using classes for these things, as I should!